# Compile errors when using json::object! tutorial example: expected identifier, found keyword

Tags: json, rust

This example code is copied directly from the `json` crate commented code:

```rust
    #[macro_use]
    extern crate json;
    
    
    fn main() {
        let mut data = object!{
            foo: false,
            bar: null,
            answer: 42,
            list: [null, "world", true]
        };
        println!("{:?}", data);
    }
```

The toml includes the dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
json="*"
```

Result:

```
error: expected identifier, found keyword `false`
 --> src/main.rs:8:14
  |
8 |         foo: false,
  |              ^^^^^ expected identifier, found keyword
  |
help: you can escape reserved keywords to use them as identifiers
  |
8 |         foo: r#false,
  |              ~~~~~~~

error: expected type, found keyword `false`
   --> src/main.rs:8:14
    |
8   |         foo: false,
    |            - ^^^^^ expected type
    |            |
    |            tried to parse a type due to this
    |
   ::: /Users/mackie/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/json-0.11.15/src/lib.rs:317:10
    |
317 |     { $( $key:expr => $value:expr ),* } => {
    |          --------- while parsing argument for this `expr` macro fragment
```

Comment: If you change `foo: false` to `foo: r#false` within the json object, does that fix the problem?

Comment: It works for me. You probably have an old version of the crate. Try `cargo tree`.

Comment: rustup update stable
info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-aarch64-apple-darwin'

  stable-aarch64-apple-darwin unchanged - rustc 1.59.0 (9d1b2106e 2022-02-23)

Comment: Using foo: r#false, (I shouldn't have to)
  |                     ^ no rules expected this token in macro call

Comment: I didn't say you rustup is out of date but your version of `json` (generally, using `*` for a dependency is a bad idea, and I think it is also prohibited on crates.io).

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I used 0.12.4 and it's working. I was going by what the crate owner recommended at : https://github.com/maciejhirsz/json-rust (see under installation.)

Comment: The project looks like it's abandoned too.

Answer (score 0):

Lesson learned; Never go by what the crate owner is recommending when they say you can use "*" for the version of the crate.

[json-rust on crates.io](https://github.com/maciejhirsz/json-rust#installation)